# Kneser-like graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

Given three integers $p,q,r$ with $p \leq q \leq r/2$, consider a graph $G(p,q,r)$ whose vertices are $q$-element subsets of $\{1,...,r\}$, and such that two vertices are adjacent if and only if their intersection has size $p$. For $p=0$ we get **Kneser graphs**; for $p=q-1$ we get **Johnson graphs**. Does this class of graph have a name, for general $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper [*Large cycles in generalized Johnson graphs*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.03006) by Kozhevnikov and Zhukovskii calls these, unsurprisingly, the **generalized Johnson graphs**. The notation they adopt is permuted from what's in the question, and I think their version is more natural: $G(n,r,s)$ is the graph with vertex set $\binom{[n]}{r}$ and an edge $AB$ whenever $|A \cap B| = s$. The graphs $G(n,r,0)$ are the Kneser graphs and the graphs $G(n,r,r-1)$ are the Johnson graphs.

Kozhevnikov and Zhukovskii mention that these are also referred to as **uniform subset graphs** (such as by Chen and Lih in the paper [*Hamiltonian uniform subset graphs*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(87)90044-X), which apparently is the first to study these graphs) and as **distance graphs**. Each term has multiple citations behind it. Personally, I think "distance graphs" is the most confusing of all of these terms, and should not be used.

The term "generalized Kneser graphs" is widely used for a related family of graphs, where the condition is that $|A \cap B| \le s$ instead of $|A \cap B| = s$.

Comment: Thank you! I see from the first paper you mention that the spectrum of such graphs is known. Do you know if the eigenvectors are also known?

Comment: I am not a specialist in these and have no idea, but - looking at the expression in that paper - I wouldn't be surprised if there were some fairly nice description for the $\binom nj - \binom n{j-1}$ eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_j$. The citation for the eigenvalues doesn't seem to be available online. I would try taking a $j$-element set $S$, defining a vector $v \in \mathbb R^{|V(G)|}$ where $v_A$ depends only on the size $|A \cap S|$, and seeing if there's an eigenvector of that form.

Comment: That is a good idea. Thanks a lot!